# Trying to write a Sudoku Checker but my loops are not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to write a function ***DoneOrNot*** passing a board ***(list[list_lines])*** as parameter. If the board is valid return **'Finished!'**, otherwise return **'Try again!'**

I first wrote two functions that extracts rows and columns from the board, then I proceeded to check if the rows and columns are valid (I check if each one of those have all the digits from 1 to 9):

```py
def done_or_not(board): 
    rows = getrows(board)
    cols = getrows(board)
    for k in cols:
        for l in range(1,10):
            if l not in k:
                return 'Try again!'
            else:
                return 'Finished!'

    for i in rows:
        for j in range(1,10):
            if j not in i:
                return 'Try again!'
            else:
                return 'Finished!'

def getrows(board):
    rows = [board[i] for i in range(len(board))]
    return rows

def getcols(board):
    columns = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            columns[i].append(board[j][i])
    return columns
```

I don't understand why this code is not working when I try for example with:

```py
a = [[1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8]
                        ,[4, 9, 8, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 5]
                        ,[7, 5, 6, 3, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9]
                        ,[6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 8, 7, 9, 2]
                        ,[5, 2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 4, 6]
                        ,[9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 1]
                        ,[2, 1, 4, 9, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7]
                        ,[3, 6, 5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4]
                        ,[8, 7, 9, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5]]
```

it seems that the loops are not executed, but when I try it with only one of the loops (either the one for columns or the one for rows) it works !

Comment: Could be that `cols = getrows(board)` should be `cols = getcols(board)`.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest you to use the numpy package: `board = numpy.array(board)`, it will be easier to extract a row: `board[0, :]` a column: `board[:, 0]` and even a block: `board[0:3, 0:3]`. Even better, you can transform the block to a 1D with `board[:3, :3].reshape(9)`, meaning all three rows, columns and blocks are represented the same as a standard 1D array and thus you only need to write a single function to check wether it have 9 different numbers all between 1 and 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return out of the function early in each for loop, you need to keep track of whether it is valid or not and then print that after both loops instead.

instead of

```
return 'Try again!'
```

use something similar to

```
valid = false
break
```

then at the start of the function initialise `valid` to `true` and you can remove the else statements that currently print out 'Finished'.

*after* both loops at the end, have a simple if statement

```
return "Finished" if valid else "Try again"
```

Comment: .. also change `getrows` to `getcols` for `cols` as mentioned in the comments